# Scala subString function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Hi I am looking for a solution it will return a substring from string for the given indexes.For avoiding index bound exception currently using if and else check.Is there a better approach(functional).

```
def subStringEn(input:String,start:Int,end:Int)={
  // multiple if check for avoiding index out of bound exception
    input.substring(start,end)
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure what you want the function to do in case of index out of bound, but `slice` might fit your needs:

```
input.slice(start, end)
```

Some examples:

```
scala> "hello".slice(1, 2)
res6: String = e

scala> "hello".slice(1, 30)
res7: String = ello

scala> "hello".slice(7, 8)
res8: String = ""

scala> "hello".slice(0, 5)
res9: String = hello
```

Answer (score 3):

`Try` is one way of doing it. The other way is applying substring only if length is greater than end using `Option[String]`.

**invalid end index**

```
scala> val start = 1
start: Int = 1

scala> val end = 1000
end: Int = 1000

scala> Option("urayagppd").filter(_.length > end).map(_.substring(start, end))
res9: Option[String] = None
```

**valid end index**

```
scala> val end = 6
end: Int = 6

scala> Option("urayagppd").filter(_.length > end).map(_.substring(start, end))
res10: Option[String] = Some(rayag)
```

**Also, you can combine `filter` and `map` to `.collect` as below,**

```
scala> Option("urayagppd").collect { case x if x.length > end => x.substring(start, end) }
res14: Option[String] = Some(rayag)

scala> val end = 1000
end: Int = 1000

scala> Option("urayagppd").collect { case x if x.length > end => x.substring(start, end) }
res15: Option[String] = None
```